# How to create a bounded vec from a normal vec?

Tags: boundedvec

Some pallet that I am configuring requires it's genesis configuration to have a `BoundedVec`. The problem I'm facing is getting to cast a `Vec` as a `BoundedVec`. How can I do this? I have taken care of supplying it's upper bound as `MaxMembers`:

```rust
let v = endowed_accounts.clone().into_iter().take(3).collect::<Vec<_>>();
let members = Into::<<BoundedVec<_, MaxMembers>>::into(v);
```

```
the trait `From<Vec<sp_runtime::AccountId32>>` is not implemented for `BoundedVec<_, MaxMembers>`
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

BoundedVec implements TryFrom, so you can use that in cases where you want an error if the BoundedVec can't be created given the length of the input vec. IE `BoundedVec::try_from(endowed_accounts);`

You can also use `BoundedVec::truncate_from()` if you don't care about any excess elements in your original vec being lost.

Answer (score 5):

You cannot just "type cast" a `Vec` into a `BoundedVec` because of the guarantees that a `BoundedVec` provides. Although there are some ways to create a `BoundedVec` from a `Vec`:

**Try Into / Try From**

This is the most careful solution since you can manually handle the case in which the bound will not fit. The `unwrap` here is only as a test. Remember to never panic in the runtime.

```rust
#[test]
#[should_panic]
fn bound_try_into_vec() {
    use frame_support::pallet_prelude::*;

    // We start with an unbounded vector with 10 elements.
    let unbounded: Vec<u8> = vec![1; 10];
    // No we try create a bounded vec with only 5 elements from the bounded vec.
    let bounded = BoundedVec::<u8, ConstU32<5>>::try_from(unbounded.clone());
    assert!(bounded.is_err(), "Does not fit");
    
    // This panics.
    let _bounded: BoundedVec::<u8, ConstU32<5>> = unbounded.try_into().unwrap();
}
```

**Defensive Truncate**

If you are in runtime code and really sure that the bound should fit, but still don't want to panic if it does not, you can use *defensive*.

```rust
#[test]
#[should_panic]
fn bound_defensive_vec() {
    use frame_support::pallet_prelude::*;
    use frame_support::traits::DefensiveTruncateFrom;

    // We start with an unbounded vector with 10 elements.
    let unbounded: Vec<u8> = vec![1; 10];
    // No we try create a bounded vec with only 5 elements from the bounded vec.
    // This panics in tests and prints an error message at runtime.
    let bounded = BoundedVec::<u8, ConstU32<5>>::defensive_truncate_from(unbounded.clone());
}
```

**Truncate**

Or if you just want to blindly ignore any superfluous elements, you can truncate. This is infallible, but also dangerous since you don't know how many elements were cut off.

```rust
#[test]
fn bound_truncate_vec() {
    use frame_support::pallet_prelude::*;

    // We start with an unbounded vector with 10 elements.
    let unbounded: Vec<u8> = vec![1; 10];
    // No we create a bounded vec with the first 5 elements.
    let bounded = BoundedVec::<u8, ConstU32<5>>::truncate_from(unbounded.clone());
    assert_eq!(bounded.len(), 5);
}
```